# do there exist finite simple characteristic quotients of the free group of rank 2?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $F_2$ be the free group of rank 2. Let $Aut^+(F_2)$ be the subgroup of $Aut(F_2)$ consisting of automorphisms of determinant 1 under abelianization.

1. Do there exist maximal normal finite index subgroups of $F_2$ which are characteristic?
2. Do there exist maximal normal finite index subgroups of $F_2$ which are invariant under $Aut^+(F_2)$?

Comment: I am sure the answers to both 1 and 2 are no, but I don't know how to prove it. If the answer were yes, then there would be a finite simple group with generators $a,b$ such that the images of all primitive elements of $F_2$ had the same order. In particular, the elements $a^ib$ and $b^ja$ would all have the same order for all $i,j \in {\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems fitting to resolve this old question by linking the following paper (joint with Lubotzky and Tiep), which answers the question in the positive:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.14302

The gist: The braid group $B_4$ contains a normal subgroup $F$ which is free of rank 2, and on which the conjugation action of $B_4$ acts via the full group $\text{Aut}^+(F)$. This means that representations of $B_4$ give rise to $\text{Aut}^+(F)$-invariant quotients of $F$ (i.e., they are "almost characteristic"). If the Zariski closure of the image of $F$ is simple (as an algebraic group), then by "spreading out and reducing mod $\mathfrak{p}$", we can often get finite simple groups of Lie type as an $\text{Aut}^+(F)$-invariant quotients. We apply this to the Burau representation, whose Zariski image is well-understood, and where in most cases we can bootstrap $\text{Aut}^+(F)$-invariant quotients to characteristic quotients. Using these techniques, we can realize $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and $\text{SU}_3(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for every $q\ge 7$ as characteristic quotients of $F_2$. We can also obtain $\text{SU}_3(\mathbb{F}_4)$ and $\text{SU}_3(\mathbb{F}_5)$ as characteristic quotients (these were first discovered in 2021 via some brute force calculations, and were the catalyst for the present paper).

Comment: What a lovely result! Are you going to "accept" your own answer?

Comment: @Will Chen: what about an infinite index version of the question: given $n \ge 2$, can the free group $F_n$ have a characteristic subgroup $N$ such that $F/N$ is an infinite simple group? Is this still open?

Comment: @AshotMinasyan That's a good question. For $n \ge 3$, I'm not sure what group would play the role of $B_4$. Note that Lochak and Funar (cited in our paper) played a similar game using quantum representations of mapping class groups of punctured surfaces to obtain finite simple char. quotients of the fun. groups of closed surfaces of genus $g\ge 2$. To realize infinite simple groups for $n = 2$, one would have to understand the image of $F$ under representations of $B_4$. At the moment I don't know how one might do this, but maybe Alex/Tiep might have some thoughts...

Comment: @AshotMinasyan Looks like the answer is yes! https://arxiv.org/pdf/2312.11684v2.pdf